# basic ssh issue

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, password

A friend set my RPI for me, and now I'm retracing all the steps. I can `ssh` into `pi@"RPi ip address"` but not `Username@"RPi ip address"` (permission denied; guess I forgot my password?). Being a complete noob, can someone explain the difference and how to reset the password to ssh into `Username@"RPi ip address"`? I have the RPi connected to the router via ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to make sure that "Username" is a valid user on your RPi. Easiest way to do this is to ssh in as "pi" (since you said you can do this) and then type `id Username`, replacing "Username" with whatever username you are looking for. If this gives you a list like this (not necessarily exactly the same of course), the user exists:

```
uid=1000(bla) gid=1000(bla) groups=1000(bla),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),118(admin),119(pulse),120(pulse-access),124(sambashare),129(mythtv)
```

If instead you get this output, the user name does not exist:

```
id: ‘bla’: no such user
```

Once you have established that the username exist, you can set a new password like so:

`sudo passwd Username`

It is more than likely however that your username on the RPi is in fact 'pi'.

Comment: Yup, Putty says the "Username' doesn't exist. But when I try to ssh through Git Bash, why does it automatically assume Username@"RPi ip address" and only ask for my password?

Comment: @yoshi For future reference, please note this is not a discussion forum; take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) if this does not make sense.  You asked your question and received an answer.  If you have another question or suddenly realize you did not ask the question you meant to ask, *ask another question.*  In this case someone else has already picked up on your comment and provided an answer to that but do not expect this as a matter of course -- again, it's not a discussion forum, and threads do not continue indefinitely with, "Okay, next I want...".

Answer (score 1):

In your latest comment, you pointed out that you cannot connect in **git Bash**.
In git Bash, when you type `ssh 192.168.0.11` (assuming this is the IP of the pi), it will by default use your local username, because you did not provide any other username. You can just provide the username by typing `ssh pi@192.168.0.11` instead.
Alternatively, create a new user on the pi with your local username. Just log into the pi with the username `pi` and then type:

```
sudo useradd username
```

With `username` being the same as your local username.

Best, read this [very good summary on user management on Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md). It also explains how to give your new user the right to run `sudo`.

Comment: Please note that doing 'useradd' indeed creates the user, but it does not automatically grant permissions/group memberships. There is more work that needs to be done to make the "Username" account work like the default 'pi' account - take a look at the output of `id pi` and `id username` to see some of the differences.

Comment: @PhilB. True. I added a link to the official raspberry pi documentation on user management which covers all the important stuff, especially making the new user a sudoer.